# How is the relegation of pole position driver managed in F1?

Tags: rules, formula-1, formula-e

If the driver who received the best time in qualifying is relegated to a "lower" grid position (for example for the change of the transmission or of the engine, etc.) what changes about the statistics for that particular driver?

Does that race count as a pole position or not?

Do Formula 1 and Formula E have different rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only time pole positions are counted in a driver's statistics in F1 are when they are officially classified in the race starting grid on pole position.

One good example would be Michael Schumacher, who, in Monaco 2012, despite qualifying on pole, started 6th after his 5-place grid penalty from crashing with Sergio Perez in Catalunya was served. [Mark Webber, who qualified 2nd, was then credited pole position when he moved up after Schumacher's penalty.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Monaco_Grand_Prix)

This would have been Schumacher's 69th pole position in his F1 career, but since he did not start the race in pole, it was not counted. [As such, his pole count remains at 68, and his last recognized pole position was still the 2006 French GP.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Formula_One_polesitters#By_driver)

Answer (score 1):

For Formula 1 (AFAIK) - the pole doesn't count or any qualifying position. Actually doesn't matter if its qualifying or the main race. Any penalties (e.g. time penalty applied after the race) can drop a drivers grid/race position.

Can find more in the FIA regulations http://www.fia.com/regulations/regulation/fia-formula-one-world-championship-110